value inequalities
When solving absolute value inequalities and determining intervals, why do we take the arithmetic mean?
To pass the exam: Your grades must be between 36 and 49.Our goal is to express this situation with absolute value. For example, how do we do this? I can figure it out but I can't understand the logic.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Because absolute value is symmetric around $0$. Therefore you want to make your interval into something symmetric around a point, and the value is the center of the interval. Let's make it more general, and you want your value $x$ to be between $a$ and $b$. Then $$\left|x-\frac{a+b}2\right|\le \frac{b-a}2$$
At the center of the interval the absolute value is $0$, and at the edges is half the width.

The idea is that
$$
|x-\mu| < \varepsilon
\text{ is equivalent to }
\mu - \varepsilon < x < \mu + \varepsilon
$$
That is, the values $x$ which satisfy $|x-\mu| < \varepsilon$ (for some given numbers $\mu,\varepsilon$) lie a distance less than $\varepsilon$ away from $\mu$.
So, for instance, if you wanted a grade range of $50$ to $70$, you have that
$$
\mu - \varepsilon = 50
\qquad
\mu + \varepsilon = 70
$$
Add these two and you get $2\mu = 120$; subtract the pair and you can get $2 \varepsilon = 20$. This lets you determinne the necessary parameters.
